# How to add nodes after a series of json calls in d3?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am recently using d3 to draw a graph like this one http://www.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassites/d3nodefocus

And the original data came from a series of JSON calls as below:

```
for(var i=0,tot=arrdip.length;i<tot;i++){
      var url = "http://219.142.70.47:3380/d/topn?devid=3&ip1="+arrdip[i]+"&type=conv&n="+5+"&starttime=null&endtime=null";
      var foo = $.getJSON(url,function(data){});
      getData.push(foo);
  }
```

After the iteration,I append my data into `allData` recursively:

```
function recurseAppend(index){
    if(index==length) {
      return ;
    }
    else{
      getData[index].then(function(data){
        allData = allData.concat(data);
      })
      index++;
      recurseAppend(index);
    }
  }
```

I wanna add nodes to my graph in `recurseAppend` method,In highcharts,I can do this using `addSeries` method ,How can I do it in d3?

I have already tried to relayout the tree but without good luck.

Comment: How is this different from any other application of D3? You simply run the code to append whatever elements you need for the series in the appropriate place.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes you are right! I didn't figure it out.I just solve my problem~